# doPost(e) not receiving data

Tags: post, google-apps-script

I have tried to use the doPost(e) function with no result. I am seeing results testing it within the hurt.it web Site- It shows the json was passed. However the spreadsheet where I am trying to collect the data has yet to show any of the results that were sent. As you can see in code below I have tried to pass "Attempt1" and "Attempt2" with 0 results

Any help is appreciated.

```js
function doPost(e) {
  
  if(typeof e !== 'undefined') {
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e.parameter));
    var attempt1 = e.parameter.text
    var attempt2 = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e.parameter));
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("IDGOESHERE");
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  
   sheet.getRange((sheet.getLastRow()+1), 1).setValue(attempt1);
  }
  // Not working show error on spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("IDGOESHERE");
  var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
  sheet.getRange((sheet.getLastRow()+1), 1).setValue("not working");
}
```

Comment: `return` prevents anything below it from running.  `return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e.parameter));`  Nothing below that line runs.

Comment: Thanks @Sandy that fixed it!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Sandy Good explained:

> return prevents anything below it from running. return
>   ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e.parameter))‌​;
>   Nothing below that line runs. –
>   I updated code to:

```js
function doPost(e) {
  
  if(typeof e !== 'undefined') {

    var attempt1 = e.parameter.text
    var attempt2 = ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e.parameter));
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("IDGOESHERE");
    var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
    var range = sheet.getRange(1,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();
    sheet.getRange((sheet.getLastRow()+1), 1).setValue(attempt1);
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(JSON.stringify(e.parameter));
  }  
}
```